# Python OpenCV - Record fixed size videos from RSTP stream

Tags: python, opencv, rtp

Good morning/afternoon/evening,

I am learning how to use OpenCV in Python, but I am facing some issues and I believe I am missing some piece in the puzzle.

### Setup

An IP camera (Bosh FLEXIDOME IP micro 5000) and my laptop connected to a PoE Switch, connected to my main router.

### What I am trying to achieve

I need to record fixed length videos from the camera (using RSTP). For example, record 30 seconds video, save it, start again. I am using VP80 because it's royalty free.

### The issue

I am hardcoding the fps as per the specs of the camera. It says that it can record from 25 fps, so I went for this number. I want 30 seconds videos.

I have tried two approaches, but the main issue is that the python loop capturing frames can't go as fast as needed to 25fps.

#### Approach 1

I calculate the number of frames I need to capture to have a 30 seconds videos. `frames_per_seconds = fps * clip_duration_in_seconds`
I loop and capture frames until I have the number of frames needed, and save the video.

This gives me 30 seconds videos (nice!) in a few minutes (?)

```
import cv2
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.178.157:554/?fmt=3')

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = 25
size = (width, height)
clip_duration_in_seconds = 5
frames_per_video = clip_duration_in_seconds * fps

if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
    raise("Error opening video stream or file")   
  
   while(True):     
        start = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S")
        output_file = f"Output_{start}.mkv"
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(
                output_file, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'VP80'), fps,
                size)
        frame_count = 0
        while(cap.isOpened() and frame_count < frames_per_video):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:                
                out.write(frame)  
                frame_count = frame_count + 1
            else: 
                raise("Broken stream")
        out.release()
```

#### Approach 2

Using `time.time()` I check that 30 seconds have elapsed. The result is a time lapse of 1-3 seconds. The code is the same as before but instead of checking `frame_count < frames_per_video` I check the time.

### Question

I guess I could lower the frame rate, but that would always be different, so how can I dynamically choose the frame rate? Or how can I change the implementation to catch all the frames?

Or am I missing something? The end goal is to have 30 seconds videos, representing 30 seconds of *real time*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Speculation for what you see:

- VP8 is too much for your computer to encode at this frame rate and size. use a simpler codec, maybe MJPG.
- maybe the network camera does *not* emit video at 30 fps

Get the CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC value from your VideoCapture before/after every frame and see if the values make sense to you.

You may have to work with presentation timestamps. That's the generalization of "frames per second" for video that can have frames at arbitrary times. Some cameras vary their frame rate when they're set to various "auto" settings.

OpenCV is not a media library. Its video reading and writing functions are merely convenience. You need more powerful APIs.

Consider using the ffmpeg library. It's a complex API, I grant you, but it's necessary complexity. The "PyAV" project wraps ffmpeg properly into python. Every other "ffmpeg" python wrapper just runs a subprocess, which gives you no information on presentation timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate the suggestions you gave me. About PyAV/ffmpeg, the main issue is their license. For a commercial product (like what I am working on), it's very strict, so I can't use it..

Comment: ffmpeg can be used commercially: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/can-i-use-ffmpeg-in-a-commercial-product

Comment: OpenCV uses ffmpeg so if you thought OpenCV was safe for commercial use (which is correct), that includes all the libraries it uses. you may have to package the respective licenses with your application to comply, maybe more, maybe less.